# Copying charts between workshseets openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file with a table and chart on the first sheet I would liked to copy it all to a different worksheet.  I use openpyxl's copy_worksheet function to do it, but it only copies the table over and completely leaves out the chart.  Does anyone know how I can copy a chart between worksheets or even between workbooks if possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to do this in your own code. openpyxl is not supposed to be a replacement for MS Excel.

Comment: Are you saying I'll need to create the chart itself with openpyxl?

Comment: That's probably the best approach. You could copy the chart but you'd still have to update the references. This is why openpyxl doesn't do it for you.